# How can I put a link in my Stack Overflow profile?

Tags: support, profile-page, hyperlinks

I would like to include a link in my profile, but no matter how I try to write it, it does not seem to work.

I have tried with:

- a simple link
- a `[]()` link
- an `a href`

but without any luck.

Here is what I have edited:

[image]

with the code:

```
Nothing special, just an IT team leader and twice daddy before all.
```

[H2P @ Miaou](https://miaou.dystroy.org/user/3510)

```
[H2P @ Miaou](https://miaou.dystroy.org/user/3510)
```

> [H2P @ Miaou](https://miaou.dystroy.org/user/3510)

```
[H2P @ Miaou](https://miaou.dystroy.org/user/3510)
```

`[H2P @ Miaou](https://miaou.dystroy.org/user/3510)`

_

And here is what is rendered:

[image]

Could it be because of my low privilege?

Comment: Plain markdown works for me. `[foo](https://example.com)` results in [foo](https://example.com) on my profile. Do all occurrences of `H2P @ Miaou` in your profile use that syntax? If so, at least the first and third occurrence *should've* resulted in links, I'd think

Comment: This looks strange. Is there an anti-spam measure preventing new users from having links in their profile ?

Comment: low rep users don't get their links rendered. Get 10 rep first.

Comment: @rene this doesn't seem to be mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/Privileges). Is there a better source ?

Comment: I have edited my question with the code of my profile and pictures of what it shows.
And I guess it could be a question of reps, thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 8):

You need to have a reputation of at least 10 to be able to add hyperlinks to your profile bio. The purpose for this restriction is to reduce spam activity. Currently.

- User with less than 10 reputation will have any link in their bio displayed as plain text.
- User with 10 or more reputation will have the any link in their bio displayed as a url and clickable.

As explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/181296/158100), this is not currently documented.